# How to draw this function graph with plot operation(TIKZ，Loop)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, foreach, loops

I wish to draw a function graph,
The analytical formula of the function is:
[image]

I can use the following code to draw an image of a specific function

But I want to be concise, how to define a letter n,

Draw the corresponding function image with the change of n

I think it should be realized by loop, but I don’t know how to do it

What needs to be done?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}     
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (-4,0)  --  (4,0)   node[below] {$ x  $};   
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (0,-0.5)    --  (0,4)   node[right] {$ y  $};
    \fill (0,0)  circle  (  0  )   node[  below   left  ] {  $  O  $  } ;

    \draw[  domain=  -3  :  3  ,samples=  300  ] plot (  \x,  {  
        abs(\x) 
    });

    \draw[  domain=  -3  :  3  ,samples=  300  ] plot (  \x,  {  
        abs(\x) + abs((\x) +  1)  
    });

    \draw[  domain=  -3  :  3  ,samples=  300  ] plot (  \x,  {     
    abs(\x) + abs((\x) +  1)  + abs((\x) +  2)  
    });
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For fun:
With Asymptote:
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
typedef real newreal(real);
newreal X(int n){
  return new real(real x){
  real s=0;
  for (int i=0; i<= n; ++i){
    s=s+abs(x+i);
  }
  return s;
};
}
path g;
g=graph(X(2),-3,1,n=300);
draw(g);
,
with PSTricks:
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](-5,1)(3,7)
\def\n{2}
\def\X{0 }%
\multido{\iB=0+1}{\fpeval{\n+1}}{ \xdef\X{\X + abs(x+\iB)} }
\psplot[plotpoints=300]{-3}{1}{\X}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
.

Answer (score 5):

Use `math` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfset{fpu=true, fpu/output format=fixed}
\tikzmath{
  function f(\x, \n) {
    real \s;
    \s = 0;
    for \i in {0,...,\n}{
      \s = \s + abs(\x + \i);
    };
    return \s;
  };
}
\pgfset{fpu=false}
\draw[->,>=stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,15) node[right] {$y$};
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {$o$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
  \draw [domain=-3:1, samples=300] plot (\x, {f(\x, \i)});
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this code is great, it looks like a perfect solution
But I still don’t understand some codes. I have not touched some corresponding concepts.
Later, I will compare the pgfmanual manual and continue to learn TIKZ in depth